# GetTokenInformation doesn't return statue of all privileges when non-elevated

Tags: c++, winapi

I created a command which uses GetTokenInformation to obtain privilege information for the current process and ran it both elevated and non-elevated.  When elevated (running as administrator), I get the state of all privileges.  When non-elevated, I only get the state of 8 privileges some of which some are enabled and some are disabled.

Why are only 8 privileges returned when running non-elevated?

Comment: and how many must be privileges returned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens can not have privileges added after being created, a non-elevated token is created with a lesser set of privileges so that even if security is broken on a non-elevated process the privilege simply is not present to be enabled. This way only the elevated process set presents an attack surface that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on **User Account Control(UAC)**, you can ref to the document about [How User Account Control works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works)

If UAC is enabled:

When you run the process(without elevation), it will get a restricted token, and the administrator is removed from the group list. Even if the current user is a member of the administrators group, the process cannot use administrator privileges.

And if UAC is disabled:

You will get the a copy of the original token with no limitation.

You can set the following register to disable(Disable UAC is not recommended):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
EnableLUA = 1 (REG_DWORD)
```

And restart the PC.